# SAS Export multiple datasets in work folder to multiple Excel workbooks with same names as datasets

Tags: excel, sas, output, export-to-excel

I would like to export all the datasets that I have within the work folder in SAS to corresponding excel workbooks/separate excel files.
So number of SAS datasets = number of the excel workbooks/files.

The excel workbooks should have the same names as the dataset names.
And the destination directory would be in Z:\

Any macros for this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Should the sheet name also be the same as the data set name?

Comment: the sheet name does not really matter. the workbook name should be the same with the dataset name.

Answer (score 3):

No need for any macro code (although you might want to use a macro variable to set the target directory).

Just use SASHELP.VMEMBER to get the list of datasets and then use CALL EXECUTE() to generate a PROC EXPORT step for each one.

```
data _null_;
  set sashelp.vmember;
  where libname='WORK' and memtype='DATA';
  call execute(catx(' '
   ,'proc export dbms=xlsx replace data=',nliteral(memname)
   ,'file=',quote(cats('Z:\',memname,'.xlsx'))
   ,';run;'
  ));
run;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I applied this solution and I got following error: 
ERROR: Temporary file for XLSX file can not be created -> sas/config/comp3/Lev1/SASApp-NL-Guest/Z:\/filename.$$1. Make sure the path name is correct and that you have write permission. 
The SAS software that I'm using is not installed in my pc but rather is a Citrix app so accessed via vpn. Perhaps that's why? If so, how can I get to a correct path name in this case?

Comment: Change 'Z:\' to a directory that is valid on your SAS server. You cannot reference DOS/Windows directories from the Unix computer where your SAS session is running.